# Knowing _irol_ function in c

Tags: c, keil

```
 prio = _irol_(prio, 2);
```

This was present in one of my code. Could you explain the `_irol_` present there.

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c166/c166__irol_.htm

Comment: Thank u for giving the link it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `integer rotate left prio by 2 bits`